# Twitter4j: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Access token already available

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, twitter, twitter4j

I am using Twitter4j for creating Twitter client with JSP and servets. When I am requesting for access token I am getting the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Access token already available.
```

Then I searched on Stack Overflow. I got [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12990031/twitter4j-access-token-already-available) where in solution the author has written:

> I was setting an Access Token hard coded by the Configuration Builder.

But they haven't mentioned how they fixed it.I am also not hardcoding access token. Here is my code

```
 StringBuffer callbackURL = request.getRequestURL();
 System.out.println("callbackurl is" + callbackURL);

 int index = callbackURL.lastIndexOf("/");
 callbackURL.replace(index, callbackURL.length(), "").append("/callback");


 ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
 cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
     .setOAuthConsumerKey(getServletContext().getInitParameter("consumerKey"))
     .setOAuthConsumerSecret(getServletContext().getInitParameter("consumerSecret"));

 TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());
 Twitter twitter = tf.getInstance();

 System.out.println("Twitter is" + twitter);

 request.getSession().setAttribute("twitter", twitter);

 RequestToken requestToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken(callbackURL.toString());
 System.out.println("request token is " + requestToken);

 request.getSession().setAttribute("requestToken", requestToken);

 System.out.println(requestToken.getAuthenticationURL());

 response.sendRedirect(requestToken.getAuthenticationURL());
```

This is the stacktrace

```
HTTP ERROR 500

Problem accessing /Demo1. Reason:

    Access token already available.

Caused by:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Access token already available.
    at twitter4j.auth.OAuthAuthorization.getOAuthRequestToken(OAuthAuthorization.java:113)
    at twitter4j.auth.OAuthAuthorization.getOAuthRequestToken(OAuthAuthorization.java:104)
    at twitter4j.TwitterBaseImpl.getOAuthRequestToken(TwitterBaseImpl.java:281)
    at com.example.Demo1.doGet(Demo1.java:69)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:565)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:479)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:521)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:227)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1031)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:406)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:965)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:349)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:449)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:910)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:634)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:609)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:599)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:534)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

Comment: Is the callback URL that you're setting the same that you configured in your Twitter API Console?

Comment: No the call back url in Twitter API Console is completely different. Its an dummy one

Comment: As @Driver said, you must use the same callback URL that you put into your Twitter API configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I met similar problem recently and I debug the source code line by line. I finally found that the configuration would take multiple sources before its ready. When setting the properties such as consumerKey, consumerSecret, it would set from these lines

```
ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
 cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
     .setOAuthConsumerKey(getServletContext().getInitParameter("consumerKey"))
     .setOAuthConsumerSecret(getServletContext().getInitParameter("consumerSecret"));
```

In addition, twitter4j will scan the classpath and find the **property files** which defines the related key value pairs. I created this file by following the instruction of the tutorial and I forget to delete this. But in the tutorial, it just told you how to get to access the api with the generated accessToken and accessSecret, which were the cause of the IllegalStatusException.

After I found this issue, and I deleted the accessToken and accessTokenSecret keys in the property file. Then problem solved.

Hope this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced same problem, that is because the access token is already available in the configuration builder. so you need to set it as null in configuration builder

```
StringBuffer callbackURL = request.getRequestURL();
 System.out.println("callbackurl is" + callbackURL);

 int index = callbackURL.lastIndexOf("/");
 callbackURL.replace(index, callbackURL.length(), "").append("/callback");


 ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
cb.setDebugEnabled(true).setOAuthConsumerKey((String) "consumerkey")
            .setOAuthConsumerSecret("consumersecret").setOAuthAccessToken(null)
            .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(null)
            .setOAuthRequestTokenURL("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token")
            .setOAuthAuthorizationURL("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize")
            .setOAuthAccessTokenURL("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token");

 TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());
 Twitter twitter = tf.getInstance();

 System.out.println("Twitter is" + twitter);

 request.getSession().setAttribute("twitter", twitter);

 RequestToken requestToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken(callbackURL.toString());
 System.out.println("request token is " + requestToken);

 request.getSession().setAttribute("requestToken", requestToken);

 System.out.println(requestToken.getAuthenticationURL());

 response.sendRedirect(requestToken.getAuthenticationURL());
```

with this code am able to run the program properly.